# Assets 2.0.3 Rename File Issue

Tags: assets, file-uploads, file-manager

Just upgraded a site from EE 2.5.2 > 2.5.5 and Assets 1.XX > 2.0.3 (along with a couple of others)

Not that I ever tried it previously but a user has reported that when right clicking an image in Assets and "rename" the modal appears but upon saving nothing happens.

Here we add "NEW" to the end
[image: Append new name]

Browser "refeshes" and filename doesn't[image: Appended name not reflected] change

I can confirm this is in fact a "real" problem, no obvious errors are being thrown either. Site is running PHP 5.3.19

Bit of a loss as to why but that's why I'm here :)

Comment: Stuart, I can definitely reproduce this. I'll look into this.

Comment: Hey Stuart - please direct bug reports directly to the developer - not here. Thanks!

Comment: Now I know it's a bug I will, sheesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next release. Thanks for the heads up!